# Using the map-function with lists (SML)

Tags: list, dictionary, sml

I have made the function `fun charListToInt (y) = map (fn x => Char.ord (x) - 64) y::[]` that takes a char list and returns a int list list with the integer code of the character (A = 1, B = 2, C = 3...).

For example: `charListToInt [#"A", #"B", #"C", #"D", #"E"] = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]`.

What I really want to do is to give the function the type `val charListToInt = fn : char list list -> int list list` instead of just having `char list` as input, like this:

```
[[#"A", #"B"], [#"C", #"D"]] = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Can this really be done by using the map-function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val charListListToIntListList = map (map (fn c => ord c - ord #"A" + 1))
```

Comment: About using `val`, what's the difference between that and using `fun`? Can you write it like `fun charListListToIntListList c = map (map (fn c => ord c - ord #"A" + 1))`?

Comment: Sure, you can, if you add an application to `c` to the end. There isn't much magic about `fun` vs `val`, though. In SML, the syntax `fun f x = e` is just an abbreviation for `val rec f = fn x => e`.